# Inserção automática indesejada ocorre toda vez que a página é atualizada em formulário PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Meu código possui um comportamento muito estranho de realizar uma **inserção dos dados não solicitada dos dados anteriores toda vez que a página é atualizada**. Algém pode me dizer o porquê disso?

- Saída da tela (Toda vez que a página é atualizada essa mensagem aparece e acontece a mesma inserção repetida com os mesmos valores).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Código PHP da inserção (Provavelmente o comportamento estranho vem daqui)

```
<?php
        require_once '../conexao/conexao.php';  
        if(isset($_POST['Inserir'])){
            $cd_produto = $_POST['cd_produto'];
            $cd_funcionario = $_POST['cd_funcionario'];
            $cd_cliente = $_POST['cd_cliente'];
            $tipo_pagamento = $_POST['tipo_pagamento'];
            $valor_item = $_POST['valor_item'];
            $quantidade = $_POST['quantidade'];
            try{
                $insercao = "INSERT INTO itens_venda (cd_produto,cd_funcionario,cd_cliente,
                tipo_pagamento,valor_item,quantidade,data_venda)
                VALUES (:cd_produto,:cd_funcionario,:cd_cliente,:tipo_pagamento,:valor_item,:quantidade,NOW())";
                $insere_dados = $conexao->prepare($insercao);
                $insere_dados->bindValue(':cd_produto',$cd_produto);
                $insere_dados->bindValue(':cd_funcionario',$cd_funcionario);
                $insere_dados->bindValue(':cd_cliente',$cd_cliente);
                $insere_dados->bindValue(':tipo_pagamento',$tipo_pagamento);
                $insere_dados->bindValue(':valor_item',$valor_item);
                $insere_dados->bindValue(':quantidade',$quantidade);
                $insere_dados->execute();
            } catch (PDOException $falha_insercao) {
                echo "A inserção não foi feita".$falha_insercao->getMessage();
            }
        }
        $seleciona_produto = $conexao->query("SELECT cd_produto, nome FROM produto");
        $resultado_produto = $seleciona_produto->fetchAll();
        $seleciona_funcionario = $conexao->query("SELECT cd_funcionario, nome FROM funcionario");
        $resultado_funcionario = $seleciona_funcionario->fetchAll();
        $seleciona_cliente = $conexao->query("SELECT cd_cliente, nome FROM cliente");
        $resultado_cliente = $seleciona_cliente->fetchAll();        
    ?>
```

- Código do formulário (Pra ajudar no entendimento)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    <title> Cadastrar venda </title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST">
        <p> Roupa:
            <select name="cd_produto" required="">
                <option value=""></option>
                <?php
                    foreach ($resultado_produto as $v1) {
                        echo "<option value='{$v1['cd_produto']}'>{$v1['nome']}</option>";
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
        </p>
        <p> Funcionário:
            <select name="cd_funcionario" required="">
                <option value=""></option>
                <?php
                    foreach ($resultado_funcionario as $v2) {
                        echo "<option value='{$v2['cd_funcionario']}'>{$v2['nome']}</option>";
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
        </p>
        <p> Cliente:
            <select name="cd_cliente" required="">
                <option value=""> </option>
                <?php
                    foreach ($resultado_cliente as $v3) {
                        echo "<option value='{$v3['cd_cliente']}'>{$v3['nome']}</option>";
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
        </p>
        <p> Pagamento:
            <select name="tipo_pagamento" required="">
                <option value=""> </option>
                <option value="Pagamento á vista">Pagamento á vista</option>
            </select>
        </p>
        <p> Valor do item: <input type="text" name="valor_item" step="0.01" required=""> </p>
        <p> Quantidade: <input type="number" name="quantidade" size=30 required=""> </p>
        <button name="Inserir"> Cadastrar venda </button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ```The page that you’re looking for used information that you entered. Returning to that page might cause any action that you took to be repeated. Do you want to continue?```  Só entendi que estou repetindo uma ação de inserção várias vezes por causa de algum erro que ainda não sei onde está no código..

Comment: Quando o usuário pede um refresh, o browser reenvia a última requisição para obter os dados atualizados. Percebe o que vai acontecer ? O submit do form é enviado novamente! Uma das maneiras de resolver é separar seu HTML do seu PHP, basta criar uma pagina por exemplo recebe.php e colocar o action do formulário apontando pra essa página, quando acabar de fazer o INSERT redireciona pra página do formulário.

Comment: Outra solução pode ser essa http://wbruno.com.br/php/diferenciar-refresh-f5-de-postsubmit/

Comment: Então não existe solução para ser na mesma página?

Comment: acho que não, a solução do link acima não é 100% segura, as sessions podem expirar

Answer (score -1):

São coisas separadas:

**Primeiro**, essa página foi criada com uma requisição HTTP do tipo POST. Dar reload numa requisição POST dispara esse alerta do navegador.

**Segundo**, essa página faz um insert no banco. Dar reload na página literalmente repete a ação, ou seja, cria um INSERT no banco.

A solução passa por separar essas duas coisas:

1. Criar um script, em um URL separado, que desenha a página que você deseja. Essa página deve ser acessada por uma requisição GET. (um link ou um redirect).
2. Esse script que "só desenha", quando quer inserir o dado, chama o script exclusivo de inserção (action do FORM aponta para o script de inserção). O script de inserção, ao terminar, redireciona o navegador para a URL que "só desenha".

E assim, reload na página que só desenha não dispara a mensagem, e por só desenhar, não reinsere o dado no banco.